# Vertical align with my inputs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried things I've seen on the internet, but nothing works, I don't know why..

I've a problem with the vertical align of my labels / inputs :
[image: the problem there]

And there is the code :

```
<!-- in <form> tag -->
<fieldset> 
    <legend style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;">General info</legend>

    <div class="row form-group pagination-centered">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <label class="control-label pull-right">Platform :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="plat" id="plat1" value="plat1" checked> plat1 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="plat" id="plat2" value="plat2"> plat2 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group pagination-centered">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <label for="version" class="pull-right">Version :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <select id="version" name="version" class="form-control text-center">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- more selects and more inputs -->
</fieldset>
<!-- more elements then end </form> -->
```

I've tried form-vertical and somethings like that, without result.

In an other topic, I've seen this :

```
   label, input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 125px;
}

label {
    color: #2D2D2D;
    font-size: 15px;
}

form, input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But nothing happends when I put this in my css..

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you show an image of the desired behaviour compared with the current behaviour? I do not understand your question.

Comment: Try using `form-group`

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/05/1422609596-nmanmana.png
Versus
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/05/1422609598-blblbl.png
I want the 2d pict. Just look the vertical align :/